# Data member/code pointer offsets

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

Could someone please help me understand the following quote as I am not getting it:

> The code for accessing a data member is more compact if the offset of
>   the member relative to the beginning of the structure or class is less
>   than 128. Example:
>
> ```
> class S2{
>     public:
>     int a[100];   //400 bytes. first byte at 0, last byte at 399
>     int b;        //4 bytes.   first byte at 400, last byte at 403
>     int ReadB() {return b;}
> };
> ```
>
> The offset of b is 400 here. Any code that accesses b through a
>   pointer or member function such as ReadB() needs to add a 4-bytes
>   offset to the pointer. **If a and b are swapped then both can be
>   accessed with a 1-byte signed integer offset**.

Where does this value of 1 byte come from? If a and b are swapped b would start at byte 0 and a would start at byte 4?

EDIT: My mistake, the array size was supposed to be 100

Comment: As far as I am aware the data members are aligned similarly in C, as to C++?

Comment: @userXXX That's possible, but this question is about C++. There's no `class` in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they're trying to point out is that the offset from the beginning the structure to the `b` member in *bytes* is > 255, and therefore cannot be calculated with a single 8-bit addition to the base pointer. More bits are required:

```
Offset           Member
0                a    // offset always zero
100*sizeof(int)  b    // offset guaranteed to be at 100*sizeof(int)
```

Reversing the field order

```
0                b    // offset always zero
sizeof(int)*     a    // offset always sizeof(int) + potential padding
```

Accessing `b` in the first case requires the base pointer + a length value that requires at least a 16-bit offset (assuming your minimum entity is 8-bits). In the second case, both `b` and `a` are well-within an offset of the base address of the structure that fits into 8 bits.

And I find it somewhat misleading the author did not at least mention potential member padding.

**EDIT** Updated to reflect the OP's change from 400 to 100 array slots for member `b`. It should be noted if this is some whacked-out embedded system with 16-bit implementation `int` values the authors point would be wrong. In that case the array would be `100 * 2` - bytes wide, which would still allow an 8-bit offset to reach the second member. For a system with 4-byte (or larger) implementation `int` values, the authors point is valid.

Comment: In addition to the apparently missing point about alignment, the first member is not necessarily guaranteed to have offset 0. If a type or any of its transitive base types have virtual members, the first member will be preceded by a pointer to the vtable. Without checking the standard, I guess that this means that there are no guarantees whatsoever what the offset of data members are since the standard doesn't concern itself with vpointers or vtables.

Comment: @bitmask the standard, thankfully, does make at least the initial member clear: it is, in fact, the only one that *is* guaranteed to always have a known offset. Per C++11 § 9.2, p20 : *"A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning,
as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment."*

Comment: IIRC, this applies to POD only. The first member of a class with virtual member functions most certainly does not have offset zero.

Comment: @bitmask correct. I misunderstood your original comment, and I apologize for that. The viable-pointer most assuredly needs to be *somewhere*.

Answer (score 4):

[EDITED after the original question changed from `a[400]` to `a[100]`.]

Their point is correct:

- In the `S2` structure as it stands, `a[100]` is 100 4 byte integers; and so is actually 400 bytes long. `a` therefore has offset 0 to 399. `b` (again a 4 byte int) will be put (at least) at an offset of 400-403:

  ```
  Offset  data
  000-399 a[0]-a[99] inclusive
  400-403 b
  ```
- If you were to swap the order of `a` and `b` the offset of `a` would be 0-3 and `b` would be 4-403:

  ```
  Offset  data
  000-003 b
  004-403 a[0]-a[99] inclusive
  ```
- In both cases, accessing `b` will use a 16 bit offset, even if early in the array, because of the potential range of offset needed. In the second case only, accessing `a` can be done with an 8 bit offset (CPU dependent). This can be faster (CPU dependent). It's all about the number of bits needed to store the offset between the start of where the class is stored and where the variable is stored.

Hope this helps. I am assuming 4 byte ints here (which is pretty common, but not universal), as I think the original quote it.

Comment: `int`s are not necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: I apologise but the array size was supposed to be 100. I typed it out wrongly- have edited my question.

Comment: @NeilTownsend: I think in your second bulletpoint you got `a` and `b` backwards.  `b` is the single int and `a` is the array.  Unless you swapped the names too, but that's just confusing

Comment: So in short, if I understand, we are looking at the distance in bytes between the first data member and the byte boundary of the last data member? Rearranging means the distance between b and a is less than 256- i.e. we could use a byte for their address offsets?

Comment: @user997112: Yes, you got it.  The 1 byte they refer to in the question is the amount of memory required to hold the offsets.  If both offsets are less than 256, the values of both offsets may be held in a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

It's talking about the space required to store the offset. In the example given, `a` is at offset 0 (which takes 1 byte to represent) and `b` is at offset 400*sizeof(int) (which probably takes 4 bytes actually). If you swap them, then `a` is at offset 0 (1 byte) and `b` is at offset 4 (1 byte).

Comment: I think you mean "a is at offset 4?" so what we're saying is that 1 byte, i.e 2^8 and 256, will allow us to reference the positions of the data member byte boundaries? If we had a third array we would probably need a short integer pointer to ensure we would refer to byte offsets beyond 256?